# Detect which button was clicked in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have the html table with columns where each of them contains button and dropdownlists.

```
<table class="table" border="1">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <p>
               Terminy
            </p>
            <br/>
            <p>
               Warsztat
            </p>
            <p>
               Liczba uczestników
            </p>
         </td>
         @foreach(DateTime date in Model.AssignedAttractions.Keys.ToList())
         {
         <td>
            <p>
               @date.ToShortDateString()
            </p>
            <p>
               @(ReservationAttractions.Days[date.DayOfWeek.ToString()])
            </p>
            <p>
               @Html.DropDownList("AttractionsAvaiableAttractions", Model.AvaiableAttractions)
            </p>
            <p>
               @Html.DropDownList("AttractionsQuantityParticipants", Model.ParticipantsQuantity)
            </p>
            <p>
               <input type="button" value="Wybierz" />
            </p>
         </td>
         }
      </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

The number of columns can be different. How can I get using javascript which button was clicked and get selected item from dropdownlists which are in columns where the clicked button is located?

Used model to fill table.

```
public class ReservationAttractions
    {

        public List<SelectListItem> AvaiableAttractions { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> ParticipantsQuantity { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<DateTime,List<string>> AssignedAttractions { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should post the generated markup, and not just the serverside code

Comment: I use one model which fills the whole table. Id of each button is good when one time can be 3 buttons and another time would be 5 buttons(different number of columns)?

Comment: Example: in one case my table contains two columns (two buttons), another time table contains six columns (six buttons). In each case how to differ which button was clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a click handler for the button. And then get the value selected in the dropdowns like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("thead td input[type='button']").click(function () {
        // gets the td for which button was clicked
        var $td = $(this).closest("td"); 
        // gets the selected Attraction for that particular td
        var selectedAttractions = $td.find("[name^='AttractionsAvaiable']").val();
        // gets the selected Participants for that td
        var selectedParticipants = $td.find("[name^='AttractionsQuantity']").val();
    });
});
```

MVC adds `name` attributes to form elements. And when there is a loop it appends extra things to differentialte the elements. The `[name^='AttractionsAvaiableAttractions']` is a [`Attribute Starts With Selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/). This will return the `select` element. From that, you can get the `.val()` to get the value selected in the dropdwons.

Comment: Wheater this accessor $td.find("[name^='AttractionsAvaiable']") can I use to remove option from this dropdownlist?

Comment: Like this: $td.find("[name^='AttractionsAvaiableAttractions '] option:eq('"+0+"')").remove();

Comment: if you want ot remove first `option` from the dropdwon:  `$td.find("[name^='AttractionsAvaiable'] option").eq(0).remove()`

Comment: And what if I want remove by value?

Comment: @maciejka `$td.find("[name^='AttractionsAvaiable'] option[value='zoo']").eq(0).remove()`

Comment: @maciejka I suggest you go through [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and practice a few examples. It's easier than you think

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the index or model id each button click handler.

```
<button type="button" onclick="onClick(@id)">
```

Then you can use that ID in your click handler to determine which model was clicked.

```
function onClick(id) {
  console.log(id + ' was clicked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind ID to each button. So based on the button ID you can make Ajax request that will populate the drop down list based on the value passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in pure vanilla JS to find which row is clicked.

```
<button type="button" onclick="handleTblBtnClick">
```

**To just get the id**

```
function handleTblBtnClick() {
console.log(arguments[0].target.id);
}
```

**To get more details like row and column number you can try this :**

```
    function handleTblBtnClick(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
    console.log("Row :" + event.target.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex + 
                "Column :" + event.target.parentNode.cellIndex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get using javascript which button was clicked and get selected item from dropdownlists which are in columns where the clicked button is located?

You can traverse up the dom till the [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) ancestor cell and so you can [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) all dropdown of your interest.

> how to differ which button was clicked?

You don't need to differ. You can only consider all dropdown are children of the same cell.

Hence, the elements are:

```
 $(this).closest('td').find('select option:selected')
```

In javascript:

```
this.closest('td').querySelectorAll('select')
```

```js
$('[type="button"]').on('click', function(e) {
    var selectedValues = $(this).closest('td').find('select option:selected').map(function(idx, ele) {
        return this.textContent;
    }).get();
    console.log('jQuery: ' + selectedValues);
})

document.querySelectorAll('[type="button"]').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
    ele.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var selectedValues = Array.from(this.closest('td').querySelectorAll('select')).map(function(ele, idx) {
            return ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].textContent;
        });
        console.log('javascript: ' + selectedValues);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>
                Terminy
            </p>
            <br/>
            <p>
                Warsztat
            </p>
            <p>
                Liczba uczestników
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>
                09/09/2017
            </p>
            <p>
                10
            </p>
            <p>
                <select>
                    <option value="a">a</option>
                    <option value="b">b</option>
                    <option value="c">c</option>
                    <option value="d">d</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <select>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="button" value="Wybierz">
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```